# Firebase ID token has incorrect "aud"

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

0.we finished this stpes follow guide.

0.1.create project on firebase and added android app
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3LQU.png)

0.2.opened Firebase Authentication
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROaqd.png)

0.3.re-generator privacy key(localmall-671bc-firebase-adminsdk-cmhnh-37939ebb19.json)
and re-download google.json for android client
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBIFX.png)

1.Android client use Firebase Authentication SDK to sign int with google

2.code for android get idtoken
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ifxhn.jpg)

3.Java server backend want to verrify the idToken，use Firebase admin SDK

4.code for initial Firebase app function
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ7BN.png)

5.coed for veryfi idToken function
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrL7f.png)

6.it always get this result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoYhM.png)

I think I followed the prompts. But you can still get the desired results

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.